# backgroundContext is not working

Tags: urlhacking

I created a link that takes me to a create new record form but when I click on cancel button it leaves a blank page. I read that backgroundContext URL hack should fix the problem but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Please, help me figure out where is the problem.

My link:

```
/lightning/o/A_133_Audit_Report__c/new?recordTypeId="012t00000004HxiAAE"&defaultFieldValues=Organization_Name__c={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id},backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F{!Account.Id}%2Fview
```

Comment: I just fix the problem.  /lightning/o/A_133_Audit_Report__c/new?recordTypeId="012t00000004HxiAAE"&defaultFieldValues=Organization_Name__c={!Account.Id}&backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Account/{!Account.Id}/view

Comment: it didn't work because I added "%2F" to my link. I guess before you had to add this annotation in order to make backgroundContext to work. But apparently salesforce change it with their new releases and now it won't work if you add these annotations.

Answer (score 0):

retURL is not actually working on lightning, you also forgot '**&**' before backgroundContext.

> Try this

```
/lightning/o/A_133_Audit_Report__c/new?recordTypeId="012t00000004HxiAAE"&defaultFieldValues=Organization_Name__c={!Account.Id}&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F{!Account.Id}%2Fview
```

Answer (score 0):

And for those using navigation in aura, backgroundContext solves the old problem of a blank background when overriding a 'New' action.

```
var pageReference = {
                "type": "standard__objectPage",
                "attributes": {
                    objectApiName: "Event",
                    actionName: "new",
                    additionalParams: ""
                },
                "state": {
                    navigationLocation: "LIST_VIEW",
                    backgroundContext: "/lightning/o/Event/home",
                    count: "1",
                    nooverride: '1',
                    defaultFieldValues: encodedValues,
                    recordTypeId: eventRecordTypeId
                }
            };
```